# How to install and use observablehq/stdlib angular 2+ project

Tags: angular, d3.js, npm-install, observablehq

I am using d3 chart in Angular 2+ project

Following [link](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-circle-packing)

I get error when using below line

```
DOM.svg(width, height)
```

What are the steps to import 'observablehq/stdlib' in angular project and using the same.

If I pass the selector directly it works. But if I get steps to import the library it would be great

```
d3.select("#id") //works
d3.select(DOM.svg(width, height)) // gives error
```

git repo for [lib](https://github.com/observablehq/stdlib#dom)

Thanks in advance

Comment: just construct the svg yourself `d3.select("#chart").append("svg").attr("width",width).attr("height",height);` https://github.com/observablehq/stdlib/blob/master/src/dom/svg.js

Comment: @rioV8 thanks... actually the lib other features which might come in handy ..any suggestion for importing in angular project

Comment: Please add more detail: if it gives an error, what is the error? And give a minimal, complete and verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@observablehq/stdlib@3"></script>
<script>

const {DOM} = new observablehq.Library;

console.log(DOM.uid);
</script>
```